# Why do I still have latches even though I include everything in sensitivity list?

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, vhdl-2008

The following is the code snippet which generates the inferred latch warning.

```
signal SDA_OUT       :   std_logic;
signal SDA_OUT_data  :   std_logic;
signal SDA_OUT_start :   std_logic;
signal SDA_OUT_stop  :   std_logic;
signal SDA_OUT_ack   :   std_logic;

select_SDA: process(start_stop, SDA_OUT_start, SDA_OUT_data, SDA_OUT_stop, SDA_OUT_ack)
begin
    SDA_OUT <= SDA_OUT_start when start_stop = "00" else 
         SDA_OUT_data when start_stop = "10" else 
         SDA_OUT_stop when start_stop = "01" else 
         SDA_OUT_ack when start_stop = "11";    
end process;
```

The warning from vivado is here.

```
[Synth 8-327] inferring latch for variable 'SDA_OUT_reg'
```

Comment: your SDA_OUT_reg doesn't even seem to be declared anywhere  ?!?

Comment: The only thing needed in the sensitivity list is start_stop as that's the only signal which would change things. Where is SDA_OUT_reg used and declared?

Comment: @citizen SDA_OUT_reg is something generated by Vivado when it's doing synthesis.

Comment: @Puffafish SDA_OUT_reg is something generated by Vivado when it's doing synthesis.

Comment: I would agree with @Puffafish it looks like start_stop is the only thing that would trigger the sensitivity list ... You might want to try it by removing all the others in the list ...

Comment: @citizen How can I avoid this inferred latch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, latches are inferred when an **if** **else** or **case** type of statement has a missing if-else or case somewhere. In other words it's incomplete.
I think you might need to check what possible values a "std_logic" defined variable may take. A quick check will reveal : type **std_logic** has 9 possible values (‘U’,’X’,’0’,’1’,’Z’,’W’,’L’,’H’,’-’)
In your case you are assuming that no other values other than the 2 bits will **start_stop** ever take. This is not what the compiler thinks.
You could try to fix it by replacing the last check, with :
SDA_OUT_ack when start_stop = **others**; (or whichever way **others** is to be used in this context to imply a check for ALL other possible values).
This would then take into account all other possible values that **start_stop** could take, and should probably remove the inferred latch...

NOTE as Dave Tweed mentioned below, one could essentially remove the last statment which implies ALL other values are taken as default, so :

```
select_SDA: process(start_stop, SDA_OUT_start, SDA_OUT_data, SDA_OUT_stop, SDA_OUT_ack)
begin
    SDA_OUT <= SDA_OUT_start when start_stop = "00" else 
         SDA_OUT_data when start_stop = "10" else 
         SDA_OUT_stop when start_stop = "01" else
         SDA_OUT_ack;    
end process;
```

Give that a try.

Comment: A simpler fix is to simply eliminate the final `when` clause altogether.